# Change logo to colour on hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using a WordPress theme called vigor.  I was wondering if I could have my logo in grey scale, and once I hover over the logo it would change in to a colour version. How can this be done. In my theme menu I have a place for custom CSS and jQuery. I also have both versions in a PNG.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible! No need for seperate PNG images.

You can use the following code, with CSS filters:

**HTML:**

```
<img id="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/">
```

**CSS:**

```
#logo {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

#logo:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/fzxn1L6q/)

Comment: Hello @Daan, my default logo image color #ccd8e6. I want to darker color on logo hover. Is this posible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS 3 Filters. Try this.

https://jsfiddle.net/1fog16gn/

```
#sampleImage {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%); 
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}

#sampleImage:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(0%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(0%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/* change image on hover */
a.Header-branding:hover img {
    visibility: hidden;
}
a.Header-branding:hover {
    background-image: url(https://beaverhero.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/trees-3464777_640-min.jpg);
    background-size: cover;`enter code here`
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.swap { 
    height: 200px; 
    width: 200px;  
    position: relative; 
}
.swap img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transition: opacity .9s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;
}
.swap img.hover, .swap:hover img.main { 
    opacity:0; 
}
.swap img.hover:hover { 
    opacity:1; 
}
```

Here's an easy way without using Javascript. Learn about the CSS-only approach to animate images on hover. For more details, visit:  https://blog.identitydesign.us/css-only-animation-image-swapping-on-hover/

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this:

```
#logo:hover {
    background-image:url('color-1.png')
}

#logo {
    background-image:url('color-2.png')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have been using this this jquery plugin: https://github.com/karlhorky/gray  for images grayscale. It's easy to use and implement as you only need to add **grayscale** class to an image or **grayscale grayscale-fade** for hover effect. I've used this plugin in may projects, because the css filters do not work in all browsers, mainly Internet explorer and I have checked many grayscale plugins out there to find the one that really gets the job done and I've been sticking to this one.

Hope it helps